# Count days between dates using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

Count days between dates

I am creating a prediction program using jupyter notebook. I have uploaded csv file with data(excel) I have to count dates between submit date(AI) and approved(T).

How can I count how long it took to approve? I changed all the null values to zero using `df.fillna(0)`.am I getting errors because I gave Zero for null values?

```
date1=pd.Series(df["Create Date"])
date2=pd.Series(df["Claim Issue Date"])

date_df = pd.DataFrame(dict(submit_date = date1, approved_date = date2))
date_df
```

How can I count the number of days it took to get approved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your columns are `datetime` type you can simply subtract two rows and will get a `Timedelta` [type object](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html). To get the number of days just use the attribute `days`, like this:

```
t_delta = date_df.loc[date1,'submit_date'] - date_df.loc[date2,'approved_date']
days = t_delta.days
```